# Antd RangePicker Component with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-hook-form

I currently have a `react-hook-form` managed form that I've added an `antd` `RangePicker` to. I'm having issues with updates to the `RangePicker` getting passed to the form object. Currently, the default values are passing fine but it's not taking any changes.

`OnChange` events seem to be being handled by the standard `Controller` method with the other field types (`Input`, etc.). My guess is I have to write something custom here but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my current `antd` `DatePicker` that is being managed with `react-hook-forms` `Controller` method.

EDIT: Updated my code to use the `render` method in react-hook-form v6+ as opposed to the `as` method. I also noticed if I don't pass any defaultValue then the RangePicker accepts and passes both the start and end dates fine. But when I set the defaultValue it always returns the default start date twice.

```
<Controller
    name="materialarrivalpickup"
    control={control}
    defaultValue={[
        moment(user.project.projectmaterialarrival),
        moment(user.project.projectmaterialpickup),
    ]}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={(props) => (
        <RangePicker
        {...props}
        format="MM/DD/YYYY"
        onChange={(e) => {
            props.onChange(e);
            console.log("Range Picker " + e);
        }}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. Apparently, `react-hook-form` was properly passing the `RangePicker` changes to my form object I just couldn't tell based on the log.

When I update the picker the Moment object (two dates) wasn't looking updated in the log produced by `react-hook-form` `watch()` (both look like they're 3/3/2020).

[image: Log pre]

But when I expand the Moment object I'm getting my updated dates (3/3/2020 and 3/5/2020).

[image: Log post]

I'll leave my working `RangePicker` + `react-hook-form` code here for anyone else that needs it.

```
<Controller
    name="materialarrivalpickup"
    style={{ marginBottom: "8px" }}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={[
    moment(user.project.projectmaterialarrival),
    moment(user.project.projectmaterialpickup),
    ]}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={(props) => (
    <RangePicker
        {...props}
        format="MM/DD/YYYY"
        onChange={(e) => {
        props.onChange(e);
        console.log("Range Picker: " + e);
        }}
    />
    )}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been an update to the react-hook-form.

Based on the comment above, it worked by passing in  component as such:

```
<Controller
    name="materialarrivalpickup"
    style={{ marginBottom: "8px" }}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={[
    moment(user.project.projectmaterialarrival),
    moment(user.project.projectmaterialpickup),
    ]}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={(props) => (
    <RangePicker
        {...props}
        format="MM/DD/YYYY"
        onChange={(e) => {
        props.fields.onChange(e);
        }}
    />)}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above worked for me when I used

```
onChange={(e) => {
        props.field.onChange(e);
        }}
```

instead